# How to return dataframe with multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the sample dataframe.

```
data = [['United Kingdom', 'High income'], ['Albania', 'Upper middle income'], ['Russia', 'Upper middle income'], ['Afganistan','Low income'], ['USA','High income']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Income Group'])
```

Here I was trying to return only countries with high income and upper middle income:

```
df = np.where(df['Income Group'] == 'High income' & df['Income Group'] == 'Upper middle income')
```

Here is the output:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

But if you use the same with other column works fine:

```
df = np.where(df['Country'] == 'USA')
```

What is the problem with column 'Income Group'?

Very appreciate for any help

Comment: what is your expacted output? it seems that you are converting dataframe to numpy array.. and also you forget `()` around each condition

Comment: @adirabargil I was just trying to return dataframe with rows where 'Income Group' equals 'High income' and 'Upper middle income'. If I put () around each condition the output is the same.

Comment: look at my answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another technique other than np.where, to slice dataframe based on multiple condition:

df[ (condition_1) & (condition_2) | (condition_3) ]

For your question, if you want to return countries with high income or upper middle income, you should use or (|) condition not and (&)

```
df_high = df[(df['Income Group'] == 'High income') | (df['Income Group'] == 'Upper middle income')]

df_high

    Country Income   Group
0   United Kingdom   High income
1   Albania          Upper middle income
2   Russia           Upper middle income
4   USA              High income
```

Comment: Nice answer! Voted up!

Answer (score 3):

[`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) can be also useful here:

```
df[df['Income Group'].isin(['High income', 'Upper middle income'])]
```

Output:

```
          Country         Income Group
0  United Kingdom          High income
1         Albania  Upper middle income
2          Russia  Upper middle income
4             USA          High income
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems from the sample you posted that you are missing `()` and you are confusing or with and so `|` instread of `&`:

```
data = [['United Kingdom', 'High income'], ['Albania', 'Upper middle income'], ['Russia', 'Upper middle income'], ['Afganistan','Low income'], ['USA','High income']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Income Group']) 
df = np.where((df['Income Group'] == 'High income') |(df['Income Group'] == 'Upper middle income'))
df
>>>(array([0, 1, 2, 4], dtype=int64),)
```

which return the indexes instead of the dataframe, if you plan to return the dataframe so do so:

```
df = df[(df['Income Group'] == 'High income') |(df['Income Group'] == 'Upper middle income')]
df
>>> Country Income Group
0   United Kingdom  High income
1   Albania Upper middle income
2   Russia  Upper middle income
4   USA High income
```

Comment: I tried | and &, the problem remains the same: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Did you copy-paste my answer and example? Or tested it in your environment with real data? Note that when you do `df=np.where...` you convert the dataframe to a numpy array of indexes... could be that you run this many times?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yea the problem was with np.where...

Answer (score 0):

You need **OR** (|) instead of **AND** (&) and you need the brackets around the individual conditions

```
data = [['United Kingdom', 'High income'], ['Albania', 'Upper middle income'], ['Russia', 'Upper middle income'], ['Afganistan','Low income'], ['USA','High income']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Income Group']) 
df = np.where((df['Income Group'] == 'High income') | (df['Income Group'] == 'Upper middle income')) # changed to OR
df
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a missing parentheses.
Because in python [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)  `&` is stronger than `==`.

You need something like:

```
df = np.where((df['Income Group'] == 'High income') & (df['Income Group'] == 'Upper middle income'))
```

update: and yes as other stated too, you need or (`|`) operator.

Comment: I tried the problem is remains the same:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [['United Kingdom', 'High income'], ['Albania', 'Upper middle income'], 
       ['Russia', 'Upper middle income'], ['Afganistan','Low income'], ['USA','High 
         income']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Income Group']) 
df2 = df[df['Income Group']=='High income']
df3 = df[df['Income Group']=='Upper middle income']
df4 = df2.merge(df3,how='outer')
print(df4)
```